# Can I change user in the Unity interface without having to type password when changing back?

Tags: unity, 12.10, security, password, users

First of all, let me emphasize that I am talking about my home computer that I use for personal use.

I have two accounts in Ubuntu: one for me, one for my wife.  We don't use separate accounts to keep secrets from one another (as far as I know), but we do like having separate internet cookies and application settings.

Ubuntu makes it convenient to switch from one user to the other without logging out, but the issue I have is that when I switch from my account to my wife's account, the screen locks so that I must type my password again when switch back.

How can I make it so that the screen doesn't automatically lock under this circumstance?

Answer (score 4):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F7</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F8</kbd> to switch between two currently running graphical user sessions.  This will keep your session running while you are on your wife's account.  Note that, if you ever have more then two users logged, in, they will be assigned to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F9</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F10</kbd>, and so on.  When you use Unity's "Switch User" feature, behind the scenes it automatically locks your screen and then switches between graphical consoles.  This method does that *without* the locking step, which is what I believe you are looking for.